# Which one is better to use for micro controller input mode? Pull-up or pull-down?

Tags: microcontroller, pullup, input, pulldown, stable

As you know it's better to keep micro controller in "Sink" mode instead of "Source" of energy because it keeps micro controller safe and stable.
For the input mode of an AVR (or any other) micro controller, should I use a pull up resistor or a pull down resistor to keep micro controller in sink mode? Which one is better?

Comment: what do you mean by `keep microcontroller in sink mode`?

Comment: No we don't know why you think it is better to keep microcontroller in sink mode so it is more stable, that makes no sense.

Comment: "Sink" means we use micro controller pins as GND and we don't use them as VCC because if we use micro controller pins as power of energy (source of energy) then we may reduce life time of it or make it unstable.

Comment: are you referring to output pins?

Comment: please don't say `as you know`, because no, I do not know, and many others also do not know

Comment: Who says it is more stable or reduces lifetime in some way than other? It makes no sense. All you have is impedances. If a pin sources 10mA it is consuming 10mA from VCC, and internal VCC may drop. If a pin sinks 10mA, it makes 10mA flow to GND, and internal GND may rise. In either case, same amount of voltage should be inside to run the MCU.

Comment: both output and input mode for pins (for example AVR micro controller). however it's easy what to do in output mode. but on input mode we face with pull-up and pull-down techniques and ever it's more complex when we face with internal and external pull-ups

Comment: It's common that microcontrollers can sink more current than they can source in output mode, but not universal and this has no impact on stability or lifetime, just design parameters.

Comment: _”of energy because it keeps micro controller safe and stable.”_ This makes no sense. What energy? Stable how? You choose internal pull-up or pull-down depending on what your interface requires.

Comment: I believe this is somewhat related to the idea that inputs consumed less power when pulled high than pulled low - for certain logic families older than I am, according to rumour.

Comment: Young @Bryan, yes.  TTL logic inputs tend to drift high with no input, and need to have current pulled from them to go low.  That's absolutely not the case with CMOS.  I don't know when you were born, but I built my first computer in 8th grade, in 1976.  It was all CMOS then, but CMOS was "that cool new stuff" at the time.

Answer (score 1):

> as you know it's better to keep micro controller in "Sink" mode instead of "Source" of energy because it keeps micro controller safe and stable.

I think most of us don't "know" that. Where did the notion come from?

> now my question is about input mode of avr (or any other) micro controller, should i use pull up resistor or pull down resistor to keep micro controller in sink mode? witch one is better?

"Sink mode" would be relevant for a microcontroller's **output**, not the input. Most microcontrollers are CMOS devices and don't source or sink significant current on the inputs other than through the pull-up/down sources, if enabled.

For an AVR (note capitals for brand name) or any other microcontroller you use input pull-ups if the input signal can only pull-down; you use pull-down if the input signal can only pull-up. If the input signal can do both pull-up and pull-down then you don't need pull resistors on the microcontroller's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either pull-up or pull-down. It makes no difference. In general that is. Some specific corner cases may exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a certain state for an input not connected to a source signal, you may use a pull-down for LOW and a pull-up for HIGH.

A combination of a pull-up and pull-down resistor may be used for a termination of a cable with its impedance to avoid reflections. The ratio of this voltage divider may be used to achieve LOW or HIGH for an unconnected input. The impedance of the cable should be equal to the parallel connection of both resistors. For high frequency AC components of the signal, the resistors of the voltage divider connected to GND and VCC are bypassed with a capacitor nearby and thus connected in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontrollers (particularly Microchip PICs) often can sink more current than they can source, due to differences in NMOS and PMOS output drivers. And the internal ground plane (Vss) and multiple ground pins may be able to carry more current than the supply (Vdd). This is good for driving standard TTL inputs which typically float high and expect active low inputs.

For inputs like tactile keyswitches I like to use pull-ups with the switches connecting inputs to ground (Vss). One reason is that the switches will float close to ground where capacitive or ohmic leakage and ESD from the operator will be more safely conducted to ground, rather than the more sensitive Vdd. Also, since logic level transition is typically at less than 1/2 Vdd and often 1 volt or less, there is inherently more noise immunity having to change from Vdd to near ground than vice-versa. And many microcontrollers have only internal weak pull-ups.

Comment: "Microcontrollers typically can sink more current than they can source".  That really differs by brand.  Some companies seem to follow a philosophy of making all the output transistors the same size, and the result is processors that can sink more than they can source.  Others (ST, for instance) seem to follow a philosophy of sizing the output transistors so that the sink and source currents are identical.  Read the data sheet.  Always, always, read the data sheet.

Comment: My experience has been mostly with Microchip PICs, which do seem to have outputs that can sink about 2-4 times as much as they source for the same voltage drop from the rails. Apparently Atmel (now Microchip) AVR chips have fairly equal source and sink characteristics. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The threshold between logic 0 and 1 might be near half supply or sometimes even below, but saying it's often 1V or less without saying a what supply voltage is very misleading. MCUs can run at large supply voltage ranges, for example 1.8V to 5.5V for ATTiny2313.

Comment: For a PIC16F1825, logic low is maximum 0.8V for 4.5-5.5V power, and 0.15 Vdd for lower supply voltage. Logic high is 2.0V minimum for 4.5-5.5V supply, and 0.25 Vdd + 0.8V for lower supply voltage. That's for TTL buffers. It's a bit different for Schmitt trigger and other inputs. So, as always, read data sheets and use good design techniques to determine choice of pull-up vs pull-down and other details.